# Creating confidence intervals for a negative binomial distribution

Tags: r, data-modeling

I am trying to create 95% confidence intervals for my model with data from a negative binomial distribution. I understand these are set up slightly different to the standard distribution but still seem to be struggling with it. I have added my model and CIs below if anyone could take a look at where I am going wrong. I think my main issue is that i am unsure of what the df -  argument should be here

model;

```
  my_mod = gam(cases ~ s(date, k = 10, bs = "cs"), data = aids, family = nb(link = 'log'))
```

Preds and CIs;

```
  preds = predict(my_mod, type = 'link', se.fit = TRUE)

  lower = preds$fit - qt(1.96, df = preds)*preds$se.fit
  upper = preds$fit + qt(1.96, df = preds)*preds$se.fit
```

error message

```
 Error in qt(1.96, df = ci_preds) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Comment: Why are you using `qt` here? Surely you just want `preds$fit - 1.96 * preds$se.fit` and `preds$fit + 1.96 * preds$se.fit`. Of course, you then need to exponentiate them to get the correct values.

Comment: Yep, thats the correct one I just didn't exponentiate them hence it wasn't working for me when i tried this way